# How to display value of rating in vue js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My json data is

```
{"status": true, "reviews": [{"review": "scdbgnhvgdbsr", "rating": 5, "by": "aravind", "pid": 8, "review_id": 1}, {"review": "helsocxdxvfbgfnhfgdf", "rating": 2, "by": "ab", "pid": 8, "review_id": 2}], "rating": 3.5}
```

I am able to display all details other than "rating" which is outside the data[]. How can I able to display rating. Here  I NEED TO DISPLAY RATING= 3.5

```
<div id="feed"> <div v-for="row in reviews">{{row.review}} </div> </div>
```

My vue js script is

```
 new Vue({ 
 el: '#feed' , 
 data: { 
 data: [], 
 reviews: [],
 pid: '{{pid}}',
 }, 
 mounted() { 
var self = this; 
 const data = {}
 data['pid'] = this.pid;
 $.ajax({ 
 url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/reviews/", 
 data: data,
 type: "POST",
 dataType: "JSON", 
 success: function (e) { 
 if (e.status == 1) { 
  self.reviews = e.reviews;
  console.log(self.reviews);
}
}
});
},
})
```

Comment: How is `reviews` defined?

Comment: Sir, I am able to print all the data other other than the rating which is at the last of json data

Comment: Maybe just `rating`? Can you share how is your vue component defined?

Comment: yes rating......

Comment: i updated the question with vue js code

Comment: You need another key to hold the `rating` since you dropped the information in the `ajax` call. Possibly add `rating: 0` to `data` property then on `ajax` success add `self.rating = e.rating`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{"status": true, "reviews": [{"review": "scdbgnhvgdbsr", "rating": 5, "by": "aravind", "pid": 8, "review_id": 1}, {"review": "helsocxdxvfbgfnhfgdf", "rating": 2, "by": "ab", "pid": 8, "review_id": 2}], "rating": 3.5}' );
alert( obj.rating);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```